# How to make org-mobile work in android?

Tags: android, org-mode

I want to view and edit my org-file in my Android phone, I synchronize files with Ubuntu one. I added such code in `.emacs`

```
(setq org-mobile-directory "~/Documents")
```

and I also set *Org Mobile Directory* as `~/Documents` in Org Mobile Group. But I can't push any org-file to my phone. When I open an org-file in Emacs and `C-c-x RET p`, Emacs shows this message.

```
Please set 'org-direcory' to the directory where your org files live
```

I don't know why after I did such setting above Emacs still gave me this message.

All I can do in my phone is simply capture a new note, I input something and they can be synchronized with my PC under the `~/Ubuntu One/mobileorg.org`. But I can't read what I load into my phone.

I read the web:[synchronizing](https://github.com/matburt/mobileorg-android/wiki/FAQ#wiki-Why_do_I_need_to_use_orgmobilepush_before_synchronizing), I found I can't find those three files in my dirctory: *checksum.dat, index.org and agendas.org.*

What do I need to view org-files in my phone, and push org-files into my phone?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Where do you store your `.org` files, which you want to export to org-mobile? For example, i store mine in `~/labor` and export file `~/labor/tasks.org`, and also use [OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org) WebDAV to synchronize with MobileOrg, so i have set:

```lisg
(setq org-directory "~/labor")
(setq org-mobile-directory "~/dl/owncloud/mobileorg")
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/labor/tasks.org"))
(setq org-mobile-inbox-for-pull "~/labor/from-mobile.org")
```

As [Pushing to MobileOrg](https://orgmode.org/manual/Pushing-to-the-mobile-application.html) says, pushing stages only the files listed in `org-agenda-files` or `org-mobile-files` and puts them  in `org-mobile-directory` retaining the same structure, as it where in `org-directory`. As [Pulling from MobileOrg](https://orgmode.org/manual/Pulling-from-the-mobile-application.html) says, `org-mobile-inbox-for-pull` is a file in `org-directory`, in which captured notes are pulled from the phone, which you will need to manually add wherever you want.

To setup:

1. Put a list of `.org` files, that you want to have on your phone, in `org-agenda-files` or `org-mobile-files` variables;
2. Set `org-directory` and `org-mobile-directory` - you've done that;
3. Setup MobileOrg on the phone with Ubuntu One directory;
4. Set `org-mobile-inbox-for-pull` to some file in `org-directory`

Your usual workflow will look like:

1. Execute `org-mobile-push` (<kbd>C-c C-x RET p</kbd>) in Emacs;
2. Synchronize the phone;
3. Do something in MobileOrg;
4. Synchronize the phone;
5. Execute `org-mobile-pull` (<kbd>C-c C-x RET g</kbd>) in Emacs;

Comment: Thanks :-)

I use ubuntuone  to synchronize with MobileOrg. my codes are: 
`(setq org-directory "~/Documents")
(setq org-mobile-directory "~/Ubuntu One/orgtest")`

I use org-mode to make notes. I have no the file: tasks.org.
I store all org files under the directory ~/Document, and ~/Ubuntu One/orgtest is the directory Mobileorg to synchronize via ubuntuone.

And now Emacs shows me: **Variable `org-mobile-inbox-for-pull` must point to a file in an existing directory**

where do I set-up the `org-mobile-inbox-for-pull` ?

Comment: It's funny. 
I added this code in .emacs `(setq org-mobile-inbox-for-pull "~/Documents/testfor.org")`  which testfor.org is a org-file I picked up randomly. now it works.  thanks.